# A family of colors. Identify me?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My family members are:

[image]

Our guests are:

[image]

Hint 1:

> Type and number of colors.

Hint 2:

> We are insects.

Can you identify me?

Comment: there are two greens and three blues...are they same?

Comment: Yes. They are same.

Comment: Why you have to make fun of color blind people?

Comment: @Marius ;) For a lot of the puzzles hear I can ask the question 'Why do you have to make fun of dumb people?'

Comment: And, to prove my point, I misspelled here.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov Should I be worried then that I understood what you meant? :D

Comment: Does it mean anything that some of the squares are closer together than others? That could be just accidental, but you never know...

Comment: @smriti There are *three* greens and three blues.

Comment: @SathiReddy It's proably not a good idea to deliberatyl ask for "guesses" here, as the first two answers proove. This is inviting VTC votes for broadness while the puzzle might be good/clever. I *assume* there is a singular solution which - once discovered - is the "obviously true, single solution" ? I'm giving this puzzle the benefit of hte doubt at the moment.

Comment: i changed it... so identify me please.

Comment: @BmyGuest..this puzzle has one and only one answer..

Comment: RGB values for colors: 
Members: (0;139;0)(174;48;47)(139;30;139)(6;51;255)(255;227;0)(0;139;0)(0;139;0)(6;51;255)(139;30;139)(6;51;255)(174;48;47). 
Guests: (139;139;139)(255;37;0)(1;253;255)

Comment: Does "my family members" *include* **you**? Or do we need to identify *the family* ? i.e. do we need to find out who of the listed colours *you* are, or do we need to find what the group of colours represents? This information should be edited into the question, I'd suggest.

Comment: I get somewhat different values for the colors than @GintasK. I get (in hex) 008000, A52A2A, 801C80, 002EFF, FFDF01, 008000, 008000, 002EFF, 801C80, 002EFF, and A52A2A for the family, with guests 808080, FF2000, and 01FDFF. I'm using good old Microsoft Paint, which gets the correct values from Lukas Rotter's identicon (or profile picture, or whatever it's called).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like these colours refer to the:

> Game called [Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hive_(game)) which is a strategic tabletop game. 
>
>  It uses hexagonal tiles to represent contents of a hive which the following pieces - 
>  
>  1 yellow bee, 2 brown spiders, 2 purple beetles, 3 green grasshoppers, 3 blue ants

In addition there are guests:

> Expansion pieces may be optionally added to the game -  
>  
>  1 gray mosquito, 1 red ladybug, 1 cyan pill bug

Comment: Tom your are intelligent..

Comment: I'm afraid I searched for the answer - it looks an interesting game - thanks for displaying it!

Answer (score 2):

1. > By color addition, you cannot obtain the yellow offspring except if you are a pure red father (like guest 2). Now if the wife is yellow and you have no kids, then you could be a lot of various other colors (there are multiple valid options).
2. > By color substraction, you'll have to be Cyan (like guest 3 or darker). Again, this excludes the totally different wife type trick.

This is for the case that you are a different color then the rest of your family members. In case you are one of them, the situation changes.

Comment: I haven't even understood the question in this direction. (See my comment for the OP above). Interesting approach to a solution.