# All around the globe

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can be found all around the globe,
>   Everyone has seen me, I hope.
>   I come in lots of colors and shapes,
>   I don't make it better, the landscape.
>   If you don't see me you'll pay
>   And you regret that all day.
>   **EDIT (two new lines):**
>   I'll tell the rules,
>   So everyone is safe from fools. (Might be vague, but had to make it rhyme)

**What am I?**

Comment: 2nd line and 5th one are kind of together. if you hope, is because you are not sure so, so many people have paid hahah

Comment: I suspect this might be too broad, since there are too many possible answers that fit the riddle as stated. Perhaps you could [edit] it to add some more lines and narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: I added two rules to make it less broad. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Traffic signpost? Next kangaroo 400km.

Comment: With the two extra lines it's much better (Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [Meta45's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42647/30011) it is

> a traffic sign

I can be found all around the globe,
Everyone has seen me, I hope.

> in every place where there are cars

I come in lots of colors and shapes,

> red triangles, blue circles, etc. Traffic lights has different colours but they are usually circles.

I don't make it better, the landscape.

> it is not its pourpose

If you don't see me you'll pay

> a ticket (or a fine). Or, in a figurate sense, you take the wrong direction

And you regret that all day.

> of course!

I'll tell the rules,

> of traffic.

So everyone is safe from fools.

> No one can choose arbitrarily the rules on the street

Comment: Wow yes! You are right, that's the answer I was looking for. I didn't really have a good explanation for the last line, but you made it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Second Try (before seeing the change that Foitn made to his riddle)

Is it:

> A car

I can be found all around the globe,

> Everywhere can be found cars. Even on the north and south pole although these look very dfferent then your normal car.

Everyone has seen me, I hope.

> Everyone must hope to see cars when crossing a road.

I come in lots of colors and shapes,

> Cars can be found in many different colors and shapes

I don't make it better, the landscape.

> Cars, roads and engine gasses are not too nice for the landscape.

If you don't see me you'll pay

> Car accident

And you regret that all day.

> You will probably have to visit a hospital (or worse), because of the accident

### ----------------------------------------

Original post (where Foitn said it was the wrong answer)

Is it:

> A street light?

I can be found all around the globe,

> Every country has street lights

Everyone has seen me, I hope.

> Everyone that isn't blind can see them. See second to last line for if you didn't see it.

I come in lots of colors and shapes,

> They can have different color's and shapes, as long as they give light.

I don't make it better, the landscape.

> Sometimes they just don't fit the landscape they are placed in

If you don't see me you'll pay

> Knocking with your head against the street light post

And you regret that all day.

> You will have a headache the rest of the day

Comment: ROFL at the second-to-last spoilertag :-P

Comment: In the last explaination, I think there is something else to regret all the day.

Comment: Wow, that's a really nice one, even though it's not right, keep on thinking :D

Comment: I'll have to change my second try, because of the new 2 lines to the riddle. Didn't see them when thinking up my second answer.

Comment: @Meta45 thank you for inspiring me an improved solution. +1

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll go for

> (Sun)light

I can be found all around the globe,

> The light of the sun can be seen from everywhere. Even at night (moon).

Everyone has seen me, I hope.

> Most people should have seen light at some point even if only [some of it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42218/a-family-of-colors-identify-me#comment125643_42218). and I think even blind people can see some contrast of light and dark.

I come in lots of colors and shapes,

> Sunlight/white light contains all wavelengths thus all colo(u)rs

I don't make it better, the landscape.

> Maybe talking about deserts or hot places where everything is burnt

If you don't see me you'll pay

> If someone can't see sunlight much they are probably in jail or something...

And you regret that all day.

> ... and usually people regret being in jail and/or not being able to see sunlight

Comment: Nice answer, sadly it's wrong

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a

> Postage Stamp

```
I can be found all around the globe,
Everyone has seen me, I hope.
```

> Possibly less true now than historically, but stamps are still used in many countries around the world

```
I come in lots of colors and shapes,
I don't make it better, the landscape.
```

> Stamps come in many colors and shapes (although mostly square, there are triangles, diamonds, circles, etc. The also sometimes depict low-resolution landscapes.

```
If you don't see me you'll pay
And you regret that all day.
```

> This sounds like a reference to Cash On Delivery, a mailing method without Stamps. People often are excessively disappointed at things that cost them objectively small amounts of money.

Comment: Nice answer, hadn't thought about that, but it's not right

Answer (score 2):

It could be:

> Torch

I can be found all around the globe,
Everyone has seen me, I hope.

> It can be seen from everywhere and most people
>  should have seen.

I come in lots of colors and shapes,

> Of course

I don't make it better, the landscape

> Sometimes they just don't fit the landscape.

If you don't see me you'll pay
And you regret that all day.

> You will see torch when darkness.

Comment: You might made a typo in your answer. Check spelling.

Comment: Even though this answer seems thought through, it's wrong. Think about the last two lines that I've added, I don't think it would fit...

Answer (score -3):

You are

> a Police Radar For Measuring Speeding Cars

It fits all the lines of the riddle.

> [image]Image credit: sciencedaily.com